# python3 dataclass with **kwargs(asterisk)

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Currently I used DTO(Data Transfer Object) like this.

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, 
        user_id: int = None,
        body: str = None):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.body = body
```

Example code is very small, But when object scale growing up, I have to define every variable.

While digging into it, found that python 3.7 supported `dataclass`

Below code is DTO used dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Test2:
    user_id: int
    body: str
```

In this case, How can I allow pass more argument that does not define into `class Test2`?

If I used `Test1`, it is easy. Just add `**kwargs(asterisk)` into `__init__`

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, 
        user_id: int = None,
        body: str = None,
        **kwargs):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.body = body
```

But using dataclass, Can't found any way to implement it.

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self,
        user_id: str = None, 
        body: str = None):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.body = body

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp = {'user_id': 'hide', 'body': 'body test'}
    t1 = Test1(**temp)
    print(t1.__dict__)
```

Result : `{'user_id': 'hide', 'body': 'body test'}`

As you know, I want to insert data with dictionary type -> `**temp`

Reason to using asterisk in dataclass is the same.

I have to pass dictinary type to class init.

Any idea here?

Comment: Pass `init=False` to the data-class decorator and implement `__init__` by hand. Sort of defeats the purpose, and without explicitly defining the attributes your data-class won't use those variables. Essentially, you don't want a dataclass.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I implement `__init__` by hand, there is no advantage for use `dataclass`. Is it a only way?

Comment: How do you expect the dataclass to know what variables to use without you explicitly enumerating them? If you want dynamic attributes (generally a poor design choice IMO), you don't really want  a dataclass.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added more information about my question. Please refer it.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change anything, although note, you don't need `**kwargs` to do that, i.e. pass a dict

Comment: Use `default_factory` as stated in the [dataclass documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#:~:text=dataclasses.field,not%20be%20set.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The basic use case for dataclasses is to provide a container that maps arguments to attributes. If you have unknown arguments, you can't know the respective attributes during class creation.

You can work around it if you know during initialization which arguments are unknown by sending them to a catch-all attribute by hand:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Container:
    user_id: int
    body: str
    meta: field(default_factory=dict)


# usage:
obligatory_args = {'user_id': 1, 'body': 'foo'}
other_args = {'bar': 'baz', 'amount': 10}
c = Container(**obligatory_args, meta=other_args)
print(c.meta['bar'])  # prints: 'baz'
```

But in this case you'll still have a dictionary you need to look into and can't access the arguments by their name, i.e. `c.bar` doesn't work.

---

If you care about accessing attributes by name, or if you can't distinguish between known and unknown arguments during initialisation, then your last resort without rewriting `__init__` (which pretty much defeats the purpose of using `dataclasses` in the first place) is writing a `@classmethod`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from inspect import signature


@dataclass
class Container:
    user_id: int
    body: str

    @classmethod
    def from_kwargs(cls, **kwargs):
        # fetch the constructor's signature
        cls_fields = {field for field in signature(cls).parameters}

        # split the kwargs into native ones and new ones
        native_args, new_args = {}, {}
        for name, val in kwargs.items():
            if name in cls_fields:
                native_args[name] = val
            else:
                new_args[name] = val

        # use the native ones to create the class ...
        ret = cls(**native_args)

        # ... and add the new ones by hand
        for new_name, new_val in new_args.items():
            setattr(ret, new_name, new_val)
        return ret
```

Usage:

```py
params = {'user_id': 1, 'body': 'foo', 'bar': 'baz', 'amount': 10}
Container(**params)  # still doesn't work, raises a TypeError 
c = Container.from_kwargs(**params)
print(c.bar)  # prints: 'baz'
```

Comment: I added more information about my question. Please refer it.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to pass unknown arguments to a dataclass constructor without rewriting it, in which case it's probably not worth it any more to use dataclasses at all. The only other option would be to provide a classmethod, I can add that to my answer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that we must exclude `ClassVar`-annotated attributes since those don't get included in the generated `__init__`. Something like `if getattr(cls.__annotations__.get(name, None), "__origin__", None) is not ClassVar:`.

Comment: @Anakhand good catch, thanks. I added a similar check.

Comment: @Arne I edited the answer to use `dataclasses.fields` instead so that the awkward comprehension was simplified. It also addresses `ClassVar` and `InitVar` cases. The edit went through without review, so revert if you feel it's not appropriate. Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Felix asking fields for the attributes is buggy in case `InitVar`s are used, which are part of a dataclasse's constructor signature, but not an attribute. The right way (which also avoids the clunky comprehension) is to use `inspect.signature` instead, I'll see if I get around to test and fix this, or you can do it if you're quicker.

Comment: @Felix It's fixed now, thanks for the heads up

Comment: I love the usage of `inspect.signature` here!~!

Answer (score 12):

Dataclass only relies on the `__init__` method so you're free to alter your class in the `__new__` method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Container:
    user_id: int
    body: str

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            initializer = cls.__initializer
        except AttributeError:
            # Store the original init on the class in a different place
            cls.__initializer = initializer = cls.__init__
            # replace init with something harmless
            cls.__init__ = lambda *a, **k: None

        # code from adapted from Arne
        added_args = {}
        for name in list(kwargs.keys()):
            if name not in cls.__annotations__:
                added_args[name] = kwargs.pop(name)

        ret = object.__new__(cls)
        initializer(ret, **kwargs)
        # ... and add the new ones by hand
        for new_name, new_val in added_args.items():
            setattr(ret, new_name, new_val)

        return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    params = {'user_id': 1, 'body': 'foo', 'bar': 'baz', 'amount': 10}
    c = Container(**params)
    print(c.bar)  # prints: 'baz'
    print(c.body)  # prints: 'baz'`
```

Comment: But `initializer(ret, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: If you're doing inheritance, you will run into a problem with this solution. You also need to save the class name so that subclasses will know not to reuse cls.__initializer. `cls.__class_name = cls.__name__`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a neat variation on this I used.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, Dict


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    data1: Optional[str] = None
    data2: Optional[Dict] = None
    data3: Optional[Dict] = None

    kwargs: field(default_factory=dict) = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        [setattr(self, k, v) for k, v in self.kwargs.items()]
```

This works as below:

```py
>>> data = MyDataclass(data1="data1", kwargs={"test": 1, "test2": 2})
>>> data.test
1
>>> data.test2
2
```

However note that the dataclass does not seem to know that is has these new attributes:

```py
>>> from dataclasses import asdict
>>> asdict(data)
{'data1': 'data1', 'data2': None, 'data3': None, 'kwargs': {'test': 1, 'test2': 2}}
```

This means that the keys have to be known. This worked for my use case and possibly others.

Comment: Nice idea. Note that 1. you can use `data.__dict__` if you want to access your kwargs fields. 2. it's slightly strange to put `field` as typing hint: you would better replace by `InitVar` (part of `dataclasses`). I tried to submit an alternative solution based on your! ^_^

Comment: ... and also, it is better to use list comprehensions to store a processed list, and to avoid it when you need to process elements (in which case, a standard loop is clearer).

Comment: **Don't use list comprehensions for side-effects*: `[setattr(self, k, v) for k, v in self.kwargs.items()]` just use a for-loop

Comment: I think you meant `kwargs: dict = field(default_factory=dict)`

Answer (score 2):

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
Clas = make_dataclass('A', 
                      ['d'], 
                      namespace={
                                 '__post_init__': lambda self: self.__dict__.update(self.d)
                      })
d = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
instance = Clas(d)
instance.a
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these changes are well-meaning but pretty clearly against the spirit of dataclasses, which is to avoid writing a bunch of boilerplate to set up a class.

Python 3.10 introduces the `match` statement and with it dataclasses get a `match_args=True` default argument in the constructor (i.e. the decorator).

This means that you get a dunder attribute `__match_args__` which stores a tuple of the init (kw)args, importantly **without** runtime inspection.

So you can just create a classmethod

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int = 0
    
    def from_kwargs(cls, **kwargs: dict) -> A:
        return cls(**{k: kwargs[k] for k in kwargs if k in cls.__match_args__})
```

It works:

```py
>>> A.from_kwargs(a=1, b=2, c=3)
A(a=1, b=2)
>>> A.from_kwargs(a=1)
A(a=1, b=0)
```

However we also have access to these same keys in Python 3.9 thanks to `__dataclass_fields__`, which is the next best option if you can’t rely on the 3.10 runtime.

```py
    def from_kwargs(cls, **kwargs: dict) -> A:
        return cls(**{k: kwargs[k] for k in kwargs if k in cls.__dataclass_fields__})
```

This gives the same result.

For the (unusual but reasonable!) use case in the question, you can just change the class method to `pop` rather than access the `kwargs` dict when building the `init_kw` dict, so that the remaining keys will be left over in `kwargs` and can be passed as their own kwarg, `rest`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int = 0
    rest: dict = {}
    
    def from_kwargs(cls, **kwargs: dict) -> A:
        init_kw = {k: kwargs.pop(k) for k in dict(kwargs) if k in cls.__match_args__}
        return cls(**init_kw, rest=kwargs)
```

Note that you have to wrap the `kwargs` in a call to `dict` (make a copy) to avoid the error of "dict size changed during iteration"

Answer (score 1):

Variation of [answer from Trian Svinit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805219/1603480):

You could use the following approach:

1. Extra attributes are added via a `kwargs` argument as such: `MyDataclass(xx, yy, kwargs={...}`)
2. `kwargs` is a `dataclasses.InitVar` that is then processed in the `__post_init__` of your dataclass
3. You can access all the values with `instance.__dict__` (because `asdict` would not detect the attributes added via `kwargs=...`

This would only use native features from dataclasses and inheriting this class would still work.

```py
from dataclasses import InitVar, asdict, dataclass
from typing import Dict, Optional


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    data1: Optional[str] = None
    data2: Optional[Dict] = None
    data3: Optional[Dict] = None

    kwargs: InitVar[Optional[Dict[str, Any]]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, k, v)


data = MyDataclass(data1="data_nb_1", kwargs={"test1": 1, "test2": 2})
print(data, "-", data.data1, "-", data.test1)
# MyDataclass(data1='data_nb_1', data2=None, data3=None) - data1 - 1
print(asdict(data))
# {'data1': 'data_nb_1', 'data2': None, 'data3': None}
print(data.__dict__)
# {'data1': 'data_nb_1', 'data2': None, 'data3': None, 'test1': 1, 'test2': 2}
```

---

If you really need to use `asdict` to get the attributes passed as kwargs, you could start to use private attributes in dataclasses to hack `asdict`:

```py
from dataclasses import _FIELD, _FIELDSInitVar, asdict, dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, Optional


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    data1: Optional[str] = None
    data2: Optional[Dict] = None
    data3: Optional[Dict] = None

    kwargs: InitVar[Optional[Dict[str, Any]]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, k, v)
                self._add_to_asdict(k)

    def _add_to_asdict(self, attr:str) -> None:
        """Add an attribute to the list of keys returned by asdict"""
        f = field(repr=True)
        f.name = attr
        f._field_type = _FIELD
        getattr(self, _FIELDS)[attr] = f

data = MyDataclass(data1="data_nb_1", kwargs={"test1": 1, "test2": 2})
print(asdict(data))
# {'data1': 'data_nb_1', 'data2': None, 'data3': None, 'test1': 1, 'test2': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Arnes Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101438/6740614), I create a class decorator which extends the dataclass decorator with the from_kwargs method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from inspect import signature


def dataclass_init_kwargs(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    cls = dataclass(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def from_kwargs(**kwargs):
        cls_fields = {field for field in signature(cls).parameters}
        native_arg_keys = cls_fields & set(kwargs.keys())
        native_args = {k: kwargs[k] for k in native_arg_keys}
        ret = cls(**native_args)
        return ret

    setattr(cls, 'from_kwargs', from_kwargs)
    return cls
```

Answer (score -1):

For this problem, you can use `default_factory`, which is described in the [dataclass documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#:%7E:text=dataclasses.field,not%20be%20set.).

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: Dict = field(default_factory=dict)
```